# pandas - converting one column to three

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, if-statement

I have one pandas series with different survey text on each row. As an example:

```
df = df.read_csv('survey_data.csv', header=None)

0 a comment
1 another comment
2 this what the person thought
3 what they felt
4 some more
```

For I want to change the series into a `dataframe` with three columns and save it as a `csv` file.

so new df would be:

```
a comment       another comment   this what the person thought
what they felt  some more
```

I actually don't care if the order gets mixed up. I will then output it to a `csv` file.

I have tried many different approaches my current one is this:

```
col_cnt = 1
df.dropna(inplace = True)  # removing null values to avoid errors
new_df = pd.DataFrame()
data = []

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    data.append(row)
    if col_cnt == 3: # we have done the three rows
        new_df.loc[len(new_df)]=list(data[1], data[2], data[3])
        col_cnt = 0
        data = [] # clear the list now that you have written it to the new df
    col_cnt = col_cnt + 1 #increment col counter for next row

    # need to write the remainder somehow
```

I get the error: `IndexError: list index out of range`

### Update

This code that I found and modified works! But I can only get two columns in the right order. Not three as I would like. Change the 2 in the range to 3 returns only one column.

new_df = pd.DataFrame()

```
index = 1
for i in range(0, len(df), 2):
    new_df['Column' + str(index)] = df[0].iloc[i:i+3].reset_index(drop=True)
    index += 1
```

Comment: Can you show an example of how the data is in your survery_data.csv and the output you would like to see?

Comment: Sorry - I seemed to have lost some formatting there

Comment: You can use `numpy reshape` if there are no null values

Comment: Ah. Just had a quick look at numpy reshape that looks very promising. Will give it a go. Thank you very much!

Comment: Please check my answer below

Answer (score 0):

If your dataframe has 6 rows like below..

```
0 a comment
1 another comment
2 this what the person thought
3 what they felt
4 some more
5 some more
```

Then you can do this to get what you want `np.reshape(df.values,(-1,3)))`

You can get a dataframe with column names using this

`df=pd.DataFrame(np.reshape(df.values,(-1,3)), columns=['col1','col2','col3']))`

Comment: I tried this: new_df = pd.DataFrame(np.reshape(df.values,(-1,3))). I got ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 4 into shape (3) but I thought the -1 would cope with that

Comment: Ah I see. That is why you asked about null values. Yes, if i divide my csv file by 3 sometimes I will get a remainder. Eg 1,4 shape needs to be reshaped as 2,3 but the last two will be null